# How to get the image of a secondary screen and place it into a window on the primary screen?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, screen-capture, imagesource

I'd like to copy an image of the desktop of my secondary screen and place it into a window on the primary screen (using C# and WPF).

I was thinking about using `Drawing.CopyFromScreen` but that's WinForm-tech and I'd like to see if it's possible using WPF only.

What would be the fasted perfoming way of doing this if I want to continously capture this image?

Can I create an `ImageSource` for the screen image somehow?

Also, if the mouse-pointer is not captured with this method I'd like to draw it into this image so I can see where the pointer is on the secondary screen without actualy seeing the screen physically.

Only need this for Windows 8.

Comment: Where is this Image that you try to copy? Just in another Window of your Application or somewhere else?

Comment: I mean the "image" of the entire desktop on that screen.

Comment: Is the requirement of Windows Vista, 7, or 8 acceptable (Non-XP)?

Comment: I only need it for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this article](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/02/08/capturing-screen-images-in-wpf-using-gdi-win32-and-a-little-wpf-interop-help) is exactly what you need. It describes how to take a screen capture and create a BitmapSource (which inherits from ImageSource) from it.